# AWS Lex V2 - Network of Bots - Error: There was an error getting the sentiment for this request. Try your request again

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-lex

Lex V2: I am creating a test network of bots. I'm using two bots each having one intent. The build is successful but when I'm trying to test it I get the error `There was an error getting the sentiment for this request. Try your request again.` for any input. I have tested both bots separately and they both work properly on the alias and associated versions. I'm not even sure where to look into.

PS: both bots are hooked to a fulfillment Lambda function and the lambda function does not get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the IAM role. The IAM role should include AmazonLexV2BotPolicy and `comprehend:DetectSentiment`